# Is SOAPpy the same thing as SOAPy?

Tags: python, soap, soappy

I would normally read the documentation to figure that out, but the links from both websites are on sourceforge and both are 404ing.

Comment: There is lots more on this topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be 2 separate projects.

**SOAPy** was written by Adam Elman (from [here](http://soapy.sourceforge.net/).)

**SOAPpy** was originally written by Cayce Ullman and Brian Matthews (from [here](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/soappy.txt).)