# Python: How can I use Twisted as the transport for SUDS?

Tags: python, soap, twisted, suds, transport

I have a project that is based on Twisted used to
communicate with network devices and I am adding support for a new
vendor ([Citrix NetScaler](http://www.citrix.com/netscaler)) whose API is SOAP.  Unfortunately the
support for SOAP in Twisted still relies on `SOAPpy`, which is badly out
of date. In fact as of this question (I just checked), [`twisted.web.soap`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/soap.py)
itself hasn't even been updated in 21 months!

I would like to ask if anyone has any experience they would be willing
to share with utilizing Twisted's superb asynchronous transport
functionality with SUDS.  It seems like plugging in a custom Twisted
transport would be a natural fit in SUDS' `Client.options.transport`, I'm just having
a hard time wrapping my head around it.

I did come up with a way to call the SOAP method with SUDS
asynchronously by utilizing `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread()`,
but this feels like a hack to me.

Here is an example of what I've done, to give you an idea:

```
# netscaler is a module I wrote using suds to interface with NetScaler SOAP
# Source: http://bitbucket.org/jathanism/netscaler-api/src
import netscaler
import os
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, threads

# netscaler.API is the class that sets up the suds.client.Client object
host = 'netscaler.local'
username = password = 'nsroot'
wsdl_url = 'file://' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'NSUserAdmin.wsdl')
api = netscaler.API(host, username=username, password=password, wsdl_url=wsdl_url)

results = []
errors = []

def handleResult(result):
    print '\tgot result: %s' % (result,)
    results.append(result)

def handleError(err):
    sys.stderr.write('\tgot failure: %s' % (err,))
    errors.append(err)

# this converts the api.login() call to a Twisted thread.
# api.login() should return True and is is equivalent to:
# api.service.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
deferred = threads.deferToThread(api.login)
deferred.addCallbacks(handleResult, handleError)

reactor.run()
```

This works as expected and defers return of the `api.login()` call until
it is complete, instead of blocking.  But as I said, it doesn't feel
right.

Thanks in advance for any help, guidance, feedback, criticism,
insults, or total solutions.

**Update:** The only solution I've found is [twisted-suds](https://github.com/aronbierbaum/twisted-suds), which is a fork of Suds modified to work with Twisted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default interpretation of *transport* in the context of Twisted is probably an implementation of `twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport`.  At this layer, you're basically dealing with raw bytes being sent and received over a socket of some sort (UDP, TCP, and SSL being the most commonly used three).  This isn't really what a SUDS/Twisted integration library is interested in.  Instead, what you want is an HTTP client which SUDS can use to make the necessary requests and which presents all of the response data so that SUDS can determine what the result was.  That is to say, SUDS doesn't really care about the raw bytes on the network.  What it cares about is the HTTP requests and responses.

If you examine the implementation of `twisted.web.soap.Proxy` (the client part of the Twisted Web SOAP API), you'll see that it doesn't really do much.  It's about 20 lines of code that glues `SOAPpy` to `twisted.web.client.getPage`.  That is, it's hooking SOAPpy in to Twisted in just the way I described above.

Ideally, SUDS would provide some kind of API along the lines of `SOAPpy.buildSOAP` and `SOAPpy.parseSOAPRPC` (perhaps the APIs would be a bit more complicated, or accept a few more parameters - I'm not a SOAP expert, so I don't know if SOAPpy's particular APIs are missing something important - but the basic idea should be the same).  Then you could write something like `twisted.web.soap.Proxy` based on SUDS instead.  If `twisted.web.client.getPage` doesn't offer enough control over the requests or enough information about the responses, you could also use `twisted.web.client.Agent` instead, which is more recently introduced and offers much more control over the whole request/response process.  But again, that's really the same idea as the current `getPage`-based code, just a more flexible/expressive implementation.

Having just looked at the API documentation for `Client.options.transport`, it sounds like a SUDS transport is basically an HTTP client.  The problem with this kind of integration is that SUDS wants to send a request and then be able to immediately get the response.  Since Twisted is largely based on *callbacks*, a Twisted-based HTTP client API can't immediately return a response to SUDS.  It can only return a `Deferred` (or equivalent).

This is why things work better if the relationship is inverted.  Instead of giving SUDS an HTTP client to play with, give SUDS and an HTTP client to a third piece of code and let it orchestrate the interactions.

It may not be *impossible* to have things work by creating a Twisted-based SUDS transport (aka HTTP client), though.  The fact that Twisted primarily uses `Deferred` (aka callbacks) to expose events doesn't mean that this is the *only* way it can work.  By using a third-party library such as `greenlet`, it's possible to provide a coroutine-based API, where a request for an asynchronous operation involves switching execution from one coroutine to another, and events are delivered by switching back to the original coroutine.  There is a project called [corotwine](https://launchpad.net/corotwine) which can do just this.  It *may* be possible to use this to provide SUDS with the kind of HTTP client API it wants; however, it's not guaranteed.  It depends on SUDS not breaking when a context switch is suddenly inserted where previously there was none.  This is a very subtle and fragile property of SUDS and can easily be changed (unintentionally, even) by the SUDS developers in a future release, so it's probably not the *ideal* solution, even if you can get it to work now (unless you can get cooperation from the SUDS maintainers in the form of a promise to test their code in this kind of configuration to ensure it continues to work).

As an aside, the reason Twisted Web's SOAP support is still based on SOAPpy and hasn't been modified for nearly two years is that no clear replacement for SOAPpy has ever shown up.  There have been many contenders ([What SOAP client libraries exist for Python, and where is the documentation for them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo) covers several of them).  If things ever settle down, it may make sense to try to update Twisted's built-in SOAP support.  Until then, I think it makes more sense to do these integration libraries separately, so they can be updated more easily and so Twisted itself doesn't end up with a big pile of different SOAP integration that no one wants (which *would* be worse than the current situation, where there's just one SOAP integration module that no one wants).

Comment: Thank you for your well-thought-out answer. I definitely think I was approaching this from the wrong layer.  By default SUDS uses `urllib2` as the client, so perhaps Twisted's Agent is a good place to start. Definitely going to give `corotwine` a look too.  I will to have to absorb this information and follow-up!  Also, I am painfully aware of the Twisted SOAP saga, although SUDS seems to be the strongest contender these days and is certainly my favorite.

Comment: I keep referring back to this answer, so I think I'm on the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: @jathanism, did you find a solution for this? I'm in a similar situation (though with the added wrinkle of an HTTP authentication handler modified to work around Microsoft's NTLM-mislabelled-as-SPNEGO bug).

Comment: In the first paragraph, "an HTTP client which SUDS can use" etc. describes what suds calls a transport, which is very different from a Twisted transport.