# consuming soap in python on appengine

Tags: python, xml, http, soap

i want to write an app (python) which reads the soap i get from the soap generating service on appengine. the services docs says: '...you will get the SOAP call with the XML packet...'
i get this packet on an url i can set.

how can i read this xml packet and parse the values i need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What SOAP client libraries exist for Python, and where is the documentation for them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a SOAP client framework, like for instance this: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Comment: even if i get this xml packet with the call and i only need to read it without invoking additional functions?

Comment: You'll get the SOAP message (XML) through a normal http request, which suds will help you achieve. It will also help you interpret the contents of the SOAP message. Just read through the documentation (https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation), it seems simple enough.

Comment: i got it out of the request body... so i wont need any further frameworks for it. thx anyway