# Python framework for SOAP web services

Tags: python, soap

I need an advice. What python framework I can use to develop a SOAP web service? I know about SOAPpy and ZSI but that libraries aren't under active development. Is there something better?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo

Comment: Not exactly. I'm searching for library that allows to create SOAP services and that guy is searching for library that allows to use SOAP services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SOAPpy before and wouldn't recommend it unless you need to *highly* customize your web service to get it to interface with other non-standard SOAP implementations.

I haven't used ZSI, but I understand that they tried to incorporate some of SOAPpy's features into ZSI.

You might try looking at [soaplib](http://wiki.github.com/jkp/soaplib/) for creating a SOAP web service.  I've heard good things, but haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: I found soaplib the best I need.

Answer (score 0):

If library is not under active development, then there are two options: it was abandoned, it has no errors anymore.

Why are you looking something else? Did you test these two?

Comment: I have some negative feedbacks about SOAPpy

Answer (score 0):

I've used suds successfully for a project where I had tried and failed to use SOAPpy.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-suds/

Comment: Suds allows to create only soap clients.