# jira SOAP and XMLRPC

Tags: python, xml, json, api, jira

I was wondering if there are urls for the various calls that can be made to jira. get issues, get users. what format are they in xml? json?

I want to write a wrapper class in python. I see the SOAP api exsists but no methods definitions in python anywhere I can find. I found the java one fairly easy.

Your help is appreciated.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Atlassian site has samples right on it.

using SOAP client to interact with Jira:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client

and using xml-rpc to interact with Jira:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+XML-RPC+Client

also check out the documentation they have for the API:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview

Comment: i updated my answer with one more link.  check out that page.. it explains how to use the remote API.  not sure what else you need.  the API is the same from any client bindings.

Comment: To clarify, there is no specific python api. You will have to use the soap or xml api's through an RPC library, both are well supported in python.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at this: http://blog.sophilabs.com/2011/08/overcoming-jira-3-13-x-remote-access-limitations-part-ii/

This is a good alternative to put up with JIRA RPC limitations.

Comment: It's true, if you can't add new SOAP methods to a JIRA instance, you're left with accessing the JIRA URLs with a script directly. Martin's post has a nice python script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian recommends REST API to communicate with Jira remotely. It is supported in Jira 5.0 and later. They still support SOAP API, but are not going to implement any new functionality there.

To use SOAP API in Python you can use any SOAP client library - [What's the best SOAP client library for Python, and where is the documentation for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206964/941776)

Here are examples in Python that use REST web services - http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-rest.html