# Best approach to use jira programmatically

Tags: c#, python, jira

I would like to be able to create/assign/and close jira tickets or entries programmatically..
I was able to google and found that jira has command line tools available as well as a soap API.
Suggestions on what approach would be the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using their API from your language of choice would seem to be the logical solution.  You haven't provided any details on what language you'd prefer to code in, though, so it's hard to provide any useful references.

If you can use Perl, [JIRA::Client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JIRA-Client) looks useful and could save you a lot of time.

EDIT: Since you've clarified that you'll use Python or C#, the following question provides some information on using JIRA's API from Python which I think will be helpful to you: [jira SOAP and XMLRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339914/jira-soap-and-xmlrpc)

This JIRA CLI in Python might also be of use: https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/10751

Comment: I apologise, it would be either python or C#

Comment: SOAP now, but get ready for REST in the future. If you use Python, I recommend using suds rather than soappy. I changed the JIRA Python CLI to use suds a few months ago.

Answer (score 13):

In c# I have been using the following dot net lib:
https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk