# Django as SOAP web-service server

Tags: python, django, web-services, soap

I need to rewrite an existing SOAP service (we have a WSDL file) in Django/Python what libs or solutions you will recomend to me?
Link are wellcome.

PS: ZSI can parse wsdl, but I don't like it, it is too old (may be I'm wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used SOAPlib. But the project has been moved and is now named [Spyne](http://spyne.io/).

Comment: Jumping from link to link of the project evolution, you'd (currently) reach [spyne](http://spyne.io)

Comment: I have implemented a SOAP web server using `Spyne` and `Flask` and I encountered [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941419/how-to-make-named-items-in-soap-web-service-response-in-flask-python) for both; do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you should check out this project

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywebsvcs/

Comment: I read about ZSI, but I didn't found solution how use ZSI+Django

Comment: Webservices is actually more of a python programming issue than django... http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices ..  u should find a couple there.. and also check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo