# suds and choice tag

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

how to generate request to method with "choice" arguments?

part of wsdl at http://127.0.0.1/service?wsdl:

```
<xs:complexType name="ByA">
<xs:sequence>
...
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ByB">
<xs:sequence>
...
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GetMethodRequest">
<xs:choice>
<xs:element name="byA" type="s0:ByA" />
<xs:element name="byB" type="s0:ByB" />
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

when I do

`from suds.client import Client
client = Client("http://127.0.0.1/service?wsdl")
print client`

I see

GetMethod()

without any arguments.

how I can call GetMethod with byA or with byB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known bug in suds
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/342

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it so:

```
class MyPlugin(DocumentPlugin):
    def setChoice(self, context):
        if not context.children:
            return
        for i in context.children:
            if i.name == "choice":
                for j in i.children:
                    i.parent.append(j)
            else:
                self.setChoice(i)

    def parsed(self, context):
        self.setChoice(context.document)


plugin = MyPlugin()
client = Client("http://127.0.0.1/service?wsdl", plugins=[plugin])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing the whole wsdl, your link is to your local machine.

The Suds Client class uses the [Service Class](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.wsdl.Service-class.html) as an instance variable for interacting with wsdl. Have you tried something like this?

`from suds.client import Client
client = Client("http://127.0.0.1/service?wsdl")
client.service.GetMethod("byA")`

or

`client.service.GetMethod("byB")`

Comment: doesn't work <ns1:Body>
  <ns0:GetMethodRequest/>
</ns1:Body> soap body is empty

Comment: Again, not sure without seeing the wsdl. The method I described is how suds calls methods on a web service.

Comment: I know how to call suds methods, I don't why suds doesn't show arguments for choices, and doesn't process args (soap body is empty)

Comment: Andrew, did you ever find a solution?