# WSDL to Python utility

Tags: python, wsdl

Is there any utility to generate Python client stub from wsdl files? I have seen wsdl2java utility from Axis and I was expecting similar utility in python. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo