# how to create python web services client in eclipse from wsdl file

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using eclipse `pydev` and want to generate a client web services from a wsdl file downloaded to my computer I have the step to do it but when I reach right click on the wsdl file web services  and generate  client but the only option I had there is the the client type is java proxy and I want to use python as `PYdev`.

On eclipse is there a way to do that generate python client type or a way to use the java proxy type with python as I am coding python better than java and want to use eclipse for this project

Comment: Are we talking soap here?

Comment: romeara answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278253/wsdl-to-python-utility

Comment: i checked the answer the all is there i know already but i want to use eclipse IDE and generate a python client web services proxy in the following path   on wsdl file imported to eclipse, right click>>>webservices>>>generate client when i am doing that i found the only option is java proxy type is there any way to add something to eclipse or use the java proxy with python