# How would I validate a wsdl document using python?

Tags: python, web-services, validation, wsdl

How would I validate a wsdl document using python?

Which python frameworks would I use?? Could I do it with just a few lines of code?? Are there any really succinct web services libraries out there?? Code examples appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SOAPpy](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/), like [this](http://diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/introspection.html). You could also have a look at the info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo).