# SUDS or SOAPpy: google app engine python

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, soap, suds

Am very new on WSDL (SOAP) web service on GAE python,
i read some services like [SOAPpy](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/webservices/tutorials/06_programming/python/soap/soappy), [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation)

actually i couldn't able to figure-out which is best and easy for consuming the services.

Guys, Could you please share me your experiences with this or any other best services which i can use in my app.

**Note:** am using Windows7 for development with Python2.5, GAE 1.6.1v

Comment: You should probably make your requirements a bit more clear, especially if you want to serve or consume a SOAP service...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f

Comment: @BernhardVallant: yes buddy..i want to consume WSDL(SOAP) service...

Comment: @BernhardVallant: Yeh..i read that too..but still had bit confusion for the best service..so suggest me as per your experience on SOAP, which is best to consume per my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUDS is very nice and would be my preferred choice, but AFAIK doesn't work on GAE without modifications. It stores the WSDL cache on file system, while on GAE you'd want to store in memcached instead. Fixing it shouldn't be too difficult, if you search you should find a couple of blog postings on the issue. There are also several versions on github, perhaps some of those support GAE.

Comment: Is that the same [blog](http://omiethenull.blogspot.in/2010/08/suds-and-appengine.html)?

Comment: Yes! It seems like suds is still in 0.4.0, so it should still apply. I haven't checked the modified versions on github.

Answer (score 0):

That's my [blog post](http://omiethenull.blogspot.in/2010/08/suds-and-appengine.html) linked in the above comment. I'm glad it was helpful, but I'm surprised that my `suds_memcache.py` is still useful. I've gone ahead and made it a gist to make it easier to get to/find and so you can easily fork it:
https://gist.github.com/jjwatt/f263b00a2827d6decbfd42a0734872fb