# How to make SOAP calls in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, soap, windows-7

I use Python 3.2. I have an API which uses SOAP. I need to perform a number of SOAP calls to modify some objects in a database. I'm trying to install a SOAP library which would work with Python 3.2 (or 2.7 if that's what it takes) in order to do my task.

If someone could give me some guidance how to go through with what library to install and how to install, I would be very grateful. I would be able to continue with the rest of my development.

Note: I heard about SOAPy but it looks like it's discontinued. I've downloaded an executable which asks me to point where I want it installed and I'm given no choices...

I'm a little lost.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f)

Comment: [This fork of suds](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) seems to support Python 3.x after running it through `2to3`.

Comment: If the installer gives you no choices it is because it is for a version of Python which you don't have installed (most likely it works with the 2.x line and you only have 3.2 installed).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your command prompt (If python already installed and you have set python path in environment variable) then
2. c:> pip install zeep
3. c:> pip install lxml==3.7.3 zeep
4. c:> pip install zeep[xmlsec]
5. c:> pip install zeep[async]

Now you are ready to create SOAP call using python
1. c:/> Python
2. >>> from zeep import Client
3. >>> client = Client('your WSDL URL');
4. result = client.service.method_name(parameters if required)
5. >>> print (result)

Comment: i believe you need to navigate to the scripts folder within python before using the pip command