# Create python soap server based on wsdl

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I have an wsdl file describing the communication server-client on a Java product.
I'm implementing a new server based on Python that will implement the same services.

Do you know of any method to create the Python server code based on the wsdl, that does not requires me to write all of the complextypes involved?

Also, what Api do you recommend?

Comment: I'm adding a bounty to this. I just can't believe there's no good solution.

Comment: BTW: do you know any libraries who can generate code (not a Python one) based on WSDL? I am wonder how hard it would be to implement such a functionality for Spyne (generate models based on WSDL).

Comment: Seems there is no mature python soap server... cannot believe this is happening to python

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When it comes to SOAP support, Python unfortunately no longer is with "batteries included". The support on client side is acceptable but on server side you are basically on your own.

You might want to look at the following for starters:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices

http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/

http://doughellmann.com/2009/09/01/evaluating-tools-for-developing-with-soap-in-python.html

If you really want to go on this route, it seems that [ZSI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywebsvcs/files/ZSI/) is the tool to use, although I have my doubts that it will work with the latest 2.x Python distribution.

Using Python 2.6.6, I tried to use ZSI 2.0 to build a web service starting from the WSDL. Got some "module has been deprecated" warnings when generating the code with `wsdl2py` and `wsdl2dispatch`, had to separately install [PyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/files/pyxml/) and hack my [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) just to make it resolve first or else I got "module ext.reader does not exist" then only to end up with a disappointing "ZSI:EvaluateException Got None for nillable(False), minOccurs(1) element" error on a basic "Hello world!" WS with a required element.

Switched to ZSI 2.1_a1 which no longer needs PyXML and `wsdl2py` does it all (what `wsdl2dispatch` did for 2.0) but still ended up in a dead end with "ZSI:EvaluateException Got None for nillable(False), minOccurs(1) element" errors.

The experience wasn't very fun but it was enough for me to form an opinion about what Python has to offer for SOAP web services... which ain't much (and that was just for basic web services nothing fancy like [WS-* specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications)). YMMV!

**EDIT :** I recently bumped into [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f), and although oriented versus a client solution, it does also mention a few libraries for building SOAP services.

Comment: Unfortunately, I came to agree with your solution. Python support for SOAP Server is not so good. Hopefully these "new" libraries have some success. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

> This question has not received enough attention.
>
> The currently accepted answer is good, but its answer is 'no'. Is there really no reasonably maintained and general solution?

Unfortunately, I don't think the negative answer is due to lack of attention to the question. There really is no support for WSDL in python. If you want to avoid the complexities of building your own soap envelope from scratch the only thing I can recommend you is building a sample envelope using any of the many soap webservices tools (soapui for instance) and then use it as a template string (I know, horrible) in your python code

**UPDATE** you could use [spyne](http://spyne.io/). It's a python RPC toolkit that among other protocols supports SOAP. It will create the WSDL for you, but if your objective is implementing the service described by the WSDL you already have then you'll have to fine tune your spyne service (written in python) until the generated WSDL matches the original