# Quickbooks Desktop how to integrate with Python

Tags: python, soap, quickbooks, qbwc

I am trying to communicate with the QuickBooks Desktop Application using the Quick Books Web Connector (must be done in Python). I am not very familiar with SOAP- I was wondering whether anyone had a template/guide for communicating with the QBWC. I have read QuickBooks Web Connector Program Guide but there was no sample Python code.

Comment: Hey, If you are still active here. Kindly respond back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirement for which language to use with the Web Connector is to have a functioning SOAP server. From the Programmer's Guide:

> #### What Platforms and Languages can I use in my Implementation?
>
> The web service should be able to run on any platform that supports standard SOAP for communication. Platforms that are known to work include Apache Tomcat (Axis)and ASP (.Net).

As long as you can roll a WSDL-first SOAP server in Python, you can interface with the Web Connector. Unfortunately, it appears that might be a significant hurdle. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14059142/1832306) for suggestions on possible ways to accomplish that.

Once you get that working, the QuickBooks SDK provides [bare-bones examples](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#WCWebService%20(C#%20ASP.NET)%20(qbxml)%20(desktop)) of a functioning web service. That should provide a sufficient template/guide for you to successfully interface with QuickBooks through the Web Connector.

Comment: Hi there are you still active?

Comment: @Santhosh hello

Comment: Hi there @JohnB , I need to ask some details about quickbook integration using python.

Comment: @JohnB , I too have some queries on integrating and creation of records in quickbooks using python. Let me know if you are free to help!