# Parse SOAP Response in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap, httpresponse, minidom

Is there a way to parse a SOAP Response (similar to XML) in Python? I have browsed through most of Stackoverflow solutions and they usually use `minidom` or `ET` functions `parse()` or `parseString()`. `parse()` takes a filename as input, while `parseString()` takes a string as input. However SOAP response type is `HTTPResponse` and hence I am always getting type mismatch error while using `parse()` or `parseString()`, so not sure how to parse the SOAP response in Python. I have also tried converting the HTTPResponse to string (failed), or using `XML` function (failed), or using `response.read()` function (failed).

I have checked that the SOAP response is correct with valid XML. I am using SUDS to call the SOAP service.

Comment: How about using a [SOAP library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-f)?

Comment: I have used https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Comment: I am actually using `SUDS` to call the SOAP service. But the question is about parsing the response received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was just to cast it to a string using

> str(response)