# python '14 fast SOAP Client

Tags: python, soap-client, suds

I am using `suds-jurko==0.6`, but its very slow when i try to connect to remote SOAP Server with caching and local WSDL.

Can anyone suggest faster, more active/recent SOAP client for Python?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find an alternate lib, I was able to run suds over multiprocessing using pathos.multiprocessing package.

Comment: do you mean you keep (e.g.) a singleton suds client instance running in one process and use pathos to communicate to the suds client?  pathos/dill is able to serialize/deserialize suds objects? standard pickle doesn't.

Comment: maybe you meant something else, I tried that but it seems dill can't pickle them either

Comment: what i meant was, with basic python multiprocessing module (not necessarily pathos mp), you can run suds - one sud session per processor. however, these suds sessions are independent of each other

Comment: ah I see, I was trying to get around the horrible memory usage of suds for service with large WSDL (eg eBay: 5.3MB WSDL) by having a single instance of client