# Parse a SOAP message with namespace in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, soap

I am trying to parse the following SOAP response using xPath and ElementTree but with no luck. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this? if it's not happy to hear other suggestions.

I have have cut down the XML to keep it readable.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:SelectCmDeviceResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ccm.cisco.com/serviceability/soap/risport70/">
     <SelectCmDeviceResult xsi:type="ns1:SelectCmDeviceResult">
        <TotalDevicesFound xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">24</TotalDevicesFound>
        <CmNodes soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CmNode[4]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
           <item xsi:type="ns1:CmNode">
              <ReturnCode xsi:type="ns1:RisReturnCode">Ok</ReturnCode>
              <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">uk-cucm-pub</Name>
              <NoChange xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</NoChange>
              <CmDevices soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CmDevice[12]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
                 <item xsi:type="ns1:CmDevice">
                    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">SIP-Trunk-to-NO-Cluster</Name>
                    <DirNumber xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <Class xsi:type="ns1:DeviceClass">SIP Trunk</Class>
                    <Model xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">131</Model>
                    <Status xsi:type="ns1:CmDevRegStat">Registered</Status>
```

What I like to achieve is to be able to go through each `item` tag under the `CmNodes` (only one item tag is shown above but there are multiple) and then under the `CmDevices/item` if the `Name` tag text is equal to *SIP-Trunk-to-NO-Cluster* then get the text under the `Status` in this case this will be "Registered"

Thanks
alexis

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for) and may go dhave mercy on your soul for having to use SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found out the solution and though I would post it here in case anyone finds this useful.

I tried to use [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/)  as suggested by @IanAuld (I think that would be the best solution) but run into SSL issues as the server I was pulling the WSDL from had a self sign cert.

The key for me to understanding name spaces was to use the following cmd and to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

```
#print all the namespaces used in the xml doc
print root.nsmap
```

I then come up with the following code to get the info I needed

```
 #get all the namespace 
 sip_trunk_name_ele = root.findall(".//item[@xsi:type='ns1:CmNode']/CmDevices[@xsi:type='soapenc:Array']/item[@xsi:type='ns1:CmDevice']/Name[@xsi:type='xsd:string']", namespaces=root.nsmap)
    for sip_trunk_name in sip_trunk_name_ele:
        print(sip_trunk_name.tag,sip_trunk_name.text)
        if sip_trunk_name.text == "SIP-Trunk-to-NO-Cluster":
            print(sip_trunk_name.getparent().tag)
            sip_trunk = sip_trunk_name.getparent()
            return print sip_trunk.findtext('Status')
```

I am sure there is a better way to use `lxml` to get the information but this worked for me