# SOAP API CLIENT with PYTHON

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, suds

I am trying to send this soap request with Python. But I cant find any useful documentation on how to create the API client in Python especially when the authentications are in the headers.

Uses the following wsdl:
https://www.bisgateway.com/brg/services/NRGCompanyReportStandard?wsdl

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:brg="http://www.dnbnordic.com/brg" xmlns:req="http://www.dnbnordic.com/brg/NRGCompanyReportStandard/request">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <brg:customerReference/>
      <brg:deliveryAddress/>
      <brg:userPassword/>
      <brg:userId>yyyy</brg:userId>
      <brg:customerCode>xxxx</brg:customerCode>
      <brg:customerCodeOwner>xxxx</brg:customerCodeOwner>
      <req:language>GB</req:language>
      <req:fromCountry>SE</req:fromCountry>
      <req:toCountry>NO</req:toCountry>
      <req:includeEmptyFields>yes</req:includeEmptyFields>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:nRGCompanyReportStandardRequest>
         <req:criteria>
            <req:countryRegNumber>937340303</req:countryRegNumber>
         </req:criteria>
      </req:nRGCompanyReportStandardRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Look here: [Python SOAP client libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for)

Comment: Thanks Andrey T, but that did not help much. I want some more concrete doc or help on how to proceed.