# How to perform a WSDL query in python

Tags: python

I've used the Zend framework in the past to create WSDL queries in PHP that perform some action, but now I need to handle WSDL queries in Python. Can somebody provide a short example of how to do this?

Comment: You can use the python suds lib to handle wsdl query's. https://webkul.com/blog/python-suds-client/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What SOAP client libraries exist for Python, and where is the documentation for them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check it on below url:

http://www.diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/index.html
or 
http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/