# Connect Nao robot with Azure

Tags: python, azure, nao-robot

I am doing a project with the robot Nao from Aldebaran.
I have to make a simple behavior where Nao play at Connect 4(4 in a row) with someone.

To do that, I had to connect Nao with windows Azure to export the image processing on the cloud, but I don't really know how to make a module for Nao to connect him on Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I could think of would be to create a WCF Web Service hosted in Azure and then you can call it from python using the help at:

[How can I consume a WSDL (SOAP) web service in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115316/how-can-i-consume-a-wsdl-soap-web-service-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I just made a web post on python and azure.
http://www.zecloud.fr/post/2012/03/04/Python-et-Azure.aspx
I use Python and Azure for my Nao Project, there are some samples in the NaoDevProg website too.
I'm ZeCloud on the NaoDevProg so you can contact me there too.