# How to call method in web service (WSDL/SOAP) in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to call methods from the web service (WSDL/SOAP) and also want to disable the certificate validation as Python does it by default. My current Python version is 3.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I consume a WSDL (SOAP) web service in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115316/how-can-i-consume-a-wsdl-soap-web-service-in-python)

Comment: I have gone thru the link provided but it did not solve my issue. It seems like the code sample does not support my version of python (v3.5). @Binke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed suds-jurko (suds installation failed in my case as I am using Python 3.5) and wrote the below code.

```
from suds.client 
import Client import ssl

#Override the default behaviour of the Python 3 for the certificate validation (though it is not recommended) 
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
url = 'https://????.asmx?wsdl'  
client = Client(url)
print(client.service.method_name(param))
```