# R SOAP/WSDL and alternatives

Tags: r, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am having great difficulty in getting a list of SOAP functions available in my company's WSDL service. I am using R.

The SSOAP package is not maintained and I have had trouble with it as it is not working for me.

To this end, I started looking at other ways to "translate" the existing taxonomy for my use as I do not have the time or the skill to do this manually. Using python or other languages for which SOAP-translating libraries exist is an alternative that I am exploring.

Is there an alternative to the SSOAP package that can save me?
Failing this, would you recommend trying with another language instead if all data is to be consumed/used in R?

Thank you

Comment: As a potential alternative, I could use Python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115316/how-can-i-consume-a-wsdl-soap-web-service-in-python) but I will have to do the call using a python library and then copy the data to R through an appropriate R library. But I am creating an extra step, which I am not even sure it would work.