# Using an API / WebService in Python instead of C#

Tags: python, c#, api, web-services, svcutil.exe

I have to use a Webservice, where on my own webserver a script should make GET requests regularly. There exists a documentation with multiple C# examples. This should work (I could not get it running on my windows pc).

---

https://integration.questback.com/integration.svc

You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

```
svcutil.exe https://integration.questback.com/Integration.svc?wsdl
```

This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:

C#

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        QuestBackIntegrationLibraryClient client = new QuestBackIntegrationLibraryClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

---

Since the server is linux based and I don´t know a piece of C# + XML, I wanted to ask if there is an way to make this run on linux server, preferable with Python (I know this question is quite vague, I´m sorry).

Thank you!

Comment: you can run c# on linux. you can also consume a webservice from python.

Comment: the nice thing with web services is that they're platform and language agnostic. so yes, there is nothing that would keep you from consuming this service from a client endpoint written in python hosted on linux. if you're stuck with C#, you can use .NET core which will run on linux.

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115316/how-can-i-consume-a-wsdl-soap-web-service-in-python answer your question

Comment: thank you, that link looks promising